# Remove null MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-charts

I want to just put blank if the field is null.

Data:

```
"history": [{
        "status": "Not Processed",
        "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2021-01-26T00:16:26.018Z"
        },
        "updatedAt": {
            "$date": "2021-01-26T00:16:26.018Z"
        }
    }, {
        "status": "Processed",
        "updatedAt": {
            "$date": "2021-01-26T00:17:25.725Z"
        },
        "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2021-01-26T00:17:25.725Z"
        }
    }],
```

Input:

```
{
  "$reduce": {
      "input": "$history",
      "initialValue": null,
      "in": {
          "$cond": {
              "if": {
                  $eq: [
                      "$$this.status",
                      "Processed"
                  ]
              },
              "then": "$$this.createdAt",
              "else": "$$value"
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Some of my data doesn't have a **processed** status in history array. I do not want to include null in my data. FYR: I'm doing this in mongodb charts.

Comment: How about adding an and condition in that.

Comment: `
"and": {
                  $ifNull: ["$$this.status", "Accepted", null]
              }
`
is this the right position after else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KdfbIYagYdZ)

You can use boolean expressions in the condition of if statement.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "res": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$history",
          "initialValue": null,
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this.status",
                      "Processed"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $ne: [
                      "$$this.status",
                      null
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              "then": "$$this.createdAt",
              "else": "$$value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to output "No Data" but it doesn't work. it still shows null.

Comment: Did you check it in the playground? Can you add a playground? In my sample, I commented status.

Comment: Hi, in the Res: I would like to put a "No Data" but it is not possible because if I put it in the initial value it will output an error **cant $subtract adate from a string**

Comment: Oh. For that can you add another project stage.